# Custom Rounding decimal numbers c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am looking to do custom rounding decimal numbers like the following

```
100.0000 => 100.0
226.4223 => 226.43
115.9080 => 115.91
```

Both input and output should be decimal numbers.

I have tried using Math.round but that does not give me the desired results.

For example: `Math.Round(226.4226, 2)` results in 226.42

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you show what you have tried and what results you did get, and we may be able to help you get the desired results.

Comment: why is this question down voted?

Comment: "226.4223 => 226.43" is not rounding by any traditional definition... You may want to clarify that you need non-standard operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
static decimal Round(decimal v)
{
    return Math.Ceiling(v * 100) / 100;
}
```

Usage:

```
decimal a = 100.00000M, b = 226.4223M, c = 115.9080M;

Console.WriteLine(Round(a).ToString("#.0#"));
Console.WriteLine(Round(b).ToString("#.0#"));
Console.WriteLine(Round(c).ToString("#.0#"));
```

Exercise for the reader: make this method round to any desired number of decimal places after the point (now it is always 2 places after the point).

Comment: thanks. I get 100.00 instead of 100.0 And the output is a string not a decimal.

Comment: Output of a method is decimal. When showing it to Console it is converted to string. For decimal 100 and 100.0 and 100.00 and 100.00000 are all the same numbers. Only their string representation differs.

Comment: @user1527762 - updated formatting strings to "#.0#", now it will show 100.0. See more info about formatting strings here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all 226.4223 shouldn't round to 226.43

Secondly if you'd like to try this:

```
double f = 1234.56789 ; 
Console.WriteLine ( "f: {0:#,###.00}", f );
```

It will print "f: 1,234.56"
The # will print a number if there is one. The 0 will print up to that amount of numbers. For Example if ###.## was 0.5 it would print 0.5 whereas 000.00 would print 0.50